# Javascript Custom Events and iFrames

Tags: javascript, html, events, iframe

We are busy with a web project where we need to capture a signature from a USB device. Getting this to work was pretty simple, but you need a browser add on.

However, once the page is placed into an iFrame (All on the same domain), it stops working. No errors or warnings, just does nothing when you click the button. It looks like the document.dispatchEvent function is not working... I think... I can see the custom event listener in Chrome dev tools.

The thing is, I added an event listener for click and that works on the page inside the iframe. It seems that dispatching custom events is not working.

Now, I'm far from an expert here and after hours of Googling and trying all sorts of different methods of which none worked I am running out of time and need help.

Is there some kind of limitation for custom events in an iframe? Security issue?

I created a JSFiddle using the example page from the company who makes the signature pads. (See below how to install browser addon). If you run the example on it's own, you will see a popup open up when you click the Sign button. You don't actually need the device for the popup to open. When the example page is in an iframe, it does nothing.

We need this to work on linux and windows, but I have the exact same issue on both platforms using google chrome.

```
<iframe style="width: 100%; height: 500px;" src="https://www.esignemcee.net/SigCaptureWeb/sign_chrome_ff_sigcapturewebsdk.html"></iframe>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/us3tm0bh/)

[Chrome add-on install guid](http://www.epadsupport.com/SigCaptureWeb/InstallationGuide.pdf)

[EPad Signature example page](https://www.esignemcee.net/SigCaptureWeb/sign_chrome_ff_sigcapturewebsdk.html)

Comment: where did you attach the JS file/code? in the document that uses iframe or the document loaded by the iframe? A document that loads and iframe cannot to my knowledge access the DOM elements of a iframe document. HOWEVER, if you attach the JS file/code to the document being loaded into the iframe the code events should works as you expect.

Comment: That custom event of yours is only local to the iframe. Try to inspect your parent dom and the iframe and check the event listeners in chrome dev tool

Comment: The code is attached to the page being loaded in the iframe. I have inspected the events in the iframe and they are there. I added an event listener for mouse click and that works in the iframe, but custom events seems not to. I don't think the listeners are the issue. Even without an event listener the popup for the signature pad should still show... it just won't do anything when you click the Finish button since there is no handler.

Comment: FireFox will actually dispatch the events, but chrome won't. Chrome is the one it has to work in though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding top to my code seems to fix the problem. If you load your page in a iframe and need to add event listeners and dispatch those event in the 'child' page, then add top to your code like:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
top.document.addEventListener("MyCustom", _CustomHandler, true);

setTimeout(function ()
{
    var MyDetail =
    {
        message: "blablabla"
    };
    var event = new CustomEvent('MyCustom', { detail: MyDetail });
    top.document.dispatchEvent(event);
}, 1000);});

function _CustomHandler(EventData){
alert(EventData.detail.message);}
```

This seems to only be an issue when trying to engage with extensions in chrome. Normal events seem to work just fine. As such the code I've added above will work either way, but this is just to show exactly how the 'top' keyword is used.

Hopefully leaving this here will prevent someone else from spending 4 days trying to figure out why dispatching some events work in an iframe and some don't when using chrome. Chrome seems to handle events dispatched for extensions slightly different. I've not been able to find any documentation on this, but custom events and working with extensions like this from javascript is knew for me. Maybe someone more knowledgeable can add some more info.